# Calculating a list of valid combinations

Tags: recursion, combinations, permutation, combinatorics

So I came up with a problem that I can’t logically solve. I’ve fleshed out an example;
You have a list of numbers that you need to output (e.g. 3x number 1 & 2x number 2) - we’ll call them ‘**target numbers**’.

You’re also given a range of **source numbers** (e.g. 2, 3, 4 and 5).

The task is to return all valid combinations of the source numbers that would allow you to produce the target numbers. You can use any combination and quantity of source numbers.

The constraints are that you can break a source number down to get to target numbers (e.g. you could break down a 5 into a 2 and a 3) but you cannot add source numbers together to get to a target number (for example you can’t add a 1 to a 1 to get to a 2).

Remainders are perfectly acceptable (e.g. using a source 3 to get to a target 2 and the remaining 1 is part of the combination but not ‘used’ in getting to the target).

In the interests of limiting results you’d also want to have a constraint that an acceptable combination does not contain any ‘totally unused’ source numbers [i.e. neither a result of being split nor a target number in the result)

So in the example target & source numbers given, the following results would be valid;
[1,1,1,2,2],[3,4],[3,3,1],[4,4]
But a [1,1,1,1,1,2] would not be valid, because you cannot join two source 1’s together to make a target 2.

I’ve thought about this logic and am largely thinking the solution involves some level of recursion, but the only examples I’ve seen are where the constraints are reversed (i.e. you can add source numbers together to reach a target number, but cannot split them to reach one)

What kind of logic would you use to generate all valid permutations in code?

Comment: What does it mean for some set of source numbers to "produce" a target number?  What do you mean by "break down" a number?

Comment: *"In the interests of limiting results you’d also want to have a constraint that an acceptable combination does not contain any ‘totally unused’ source numbers [i.e. neither a result of being split nor a target number in the result)

So in the example target & source numbers given, the following results would be valid; [1,1,1,2,2]"*  <<< I don't understand. In combination [1,1,1,2,2], you've left source numbers 3, 4 and 5 totally unused! Isn't that invalid?

Comment: Ignoring the part about totally unused source numbers: Since source numbers can be split and are not limited in quantity, it looks like you could replace `source` with `{n such that n <= max(source)}` and get an equivalent result. And so your problem is exactly the coin change problem, where you have denominations in all integer numbers from 1 up to max(source).

Comment: @ScottHunter thanks - so source numbers would effectively be your options of numbers you can use. To break down a number is to effectively split it - so if your target is a 2 and a 3, you can split a 5 into a 2 and a 3, or a 6 into a 3, 2, and a 1

Comment: @Stef - so the 'unused' is not a source number that isn't part of your valid combination - it's a remainder. So target 2&2, could use source 4 and have no remainder, or 5 and have an 'unused' remainder of 1. If you used a source of x2 number 4, you'd reach the 2&2 target, but also have one number 4 that was never utilised in the combination. This is to stop the list of valid combinations being infinite (a million number 4s would also be valid). Hope that's clearer!

Comment: If the result is some "combination and quantity of source numbers", how can it include something that is *not* a source number?

Comment: @Stef - thanks for the comment on the coin change problem! I think there's a fundamental difference - you don't know which source numbers to use? The fixed constant is the target numbers, so if I have source number of 12 and 10, and I need to get 3x5's and 2x2's, I can use a source of 2x10 or 2x12 - doesn't the coin problem permit you only to reach the total amount you're targeting?

Comment: @ScottHunter very valid point. To simplify - a valid combination of source numbers should not include one that would be unused in the theoretical process of going from source to target. Example; if your target was x3 4's, a combination of source numbers x4 5's _could_ create x3 4's (by removing 1 from x3 of the 5's) but there would be a redundant 5 that would not be used to transform from source to target. Therefore this combination would not been seen as 'valid'

Comment: Oh yes, you're absolutely right, sorry